# How to echo the attribute title

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I think this is a simple question, but can't seem to find the answer.

I have used this code and it works fine:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('my_attribute'); ?>
```

the only thing is, it is just showing the attribute value not the title.
How can I add the attribute title to this code/

Answer (score 1):

i think this helping you ..

get attribute collection

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');
```

get attribute type

```
$attribute->getAttributeType();
```

get attribute Label

```
$attribute->getFrontendLabel();
```

get attribute default value

```
$attribute->getDefaultValue();
```

check if the attribute is visible

```
$attribute->getIsVisible();
```

check if the attribute is required

```
$attribute->getIsRequired();
```

get attribute value

```
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMyAttribute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should give you what you need:

```
$attribute->getFrontendLabel();
```